# Server responds half of the page

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, iis-7

After I recently deployed my site to a new server, one particular aspx page started to act up. In IE the page wouldn't render and gave a "Page cannot be displayed" while FF partially rendered the page, but no functionality would work. A bit of investigation led to the discovery that only about half of the code is rendered on the page (through "show source") and the server response seemingly random cuts off the code at different locations with each request. The cut is made without any logical place and cuts at the middle of words e.g. The only thing that is similar between the responses is that the response size is roughly around 25kB (however, this varies as well with sizes between 15kB to 28kB).

I have deployed the same code to another server which works perfectly (which gets a full response at 53kB) and it also works if I try to reach the aspx page from within the problem server, but not if I try to reach the page from outside the server. This leads me to believe there is some kind of IIS limit or timeout that I'm not aware of that cuts the response short?

Both the problem server and the working server have similar setups (IIS7). I've tried everything I can think of but nothing seems to solve it, anything that could point in a new direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify: all the other pages work fine (including those with outputs longer than 28kB)?

Comment: This is probably a gzip issue and content length set with error number

Comment: Are you using Ajax.net in this page?

Comment: Thank you for your answers :).

Tim Rogers: All the other pages work fine, event those with longer outputs.

Aristos: Not entirely sure how you mean? If it is any help, the content-length param of the response header is correct (i.e. around 56kB), but the responses content is not.
Hanlet Escaño: Nope, no ajax requests on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forgot to update this question but I figured out the problem a while ago. Maybe someone else will encounter a similar issue in the future :).

The problem was a third party system for monitoring and detecting threats that were connected to the network. For some reason this system determined that the request the aspx-page were performing could be perceived as malicious and simply blocked it. It took a different amount of time for the system to assess the request each time and therefore the responses were of different sizes. We added a rule to make an exception for this page/type of request and since then it has worked wonderfully!

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this same problem, but with classic asp. One page we managed to get working by disabling dynamic content compression from site (checkbox found under Compression in IIS Manager), but now the problem is with another page and nothing seems to help with it.

From IIS-log files I checked that response size for this page send by IIS is 65536 bytes if the page is reached from outside the server. But if the page is reached from within the server size is 142540 bytes.
Other, even larger pages works fine, but this one just won't work.

EDIT:
Ok, now I managed to get the page working. I set maxBandwidth (http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/sites/site/limits) value from site to 200000 (which is much smaller than default value 4294967295) and now the page magically opens! I have no idea why this helped, but as long as it works...

Comment: Sounds a lot like my problem. Tried your approach and changed around the limits, without the same results unfortunately :/.